# How to add and remove classes in a div?

Tags: jquery, html, class

I have some div in a loop and would like to change the classes according to what is clicked on. Please see codes below:

My html:

```
<div class="Active"></div>
<div class="inactive"></div>
<div class="inactive"></div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('div.inactive').on('click',function()
    {
        //run some codes
        $(this)
            .removeClass('inactive')
            .addClass('Active')
            .closest('div')
            .find('.Active')
            .removeClass('Active')
            .addClass('inactive');
    });
});
```

The div with the active class is the current selection that is being displayed. This is not clickable. The div's with the inactive classes are the clickable options. If the user click on an inactive div, the class of that div should change to active (which will be the new selection being displayed) and the previous div with the active class should be changed to inactive making that a clickable options. I did not place the CSS codes because it is irrelevant, all I want is to switch classes depending on the clicked option.

Can someone please take a look at my codes and tell me where I am failing in this?

Comment: You need to call `.end()` at the end of each selection chain that you want to close and roll back to the *original* selection in the chain (start over). Otherwise you're just applying it over and over to the last selection in the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `.` for the class name that is passed to `find` method, also `closest` selects the closest parent element, you are removing the `Active` class from the clicked element too.

```
$('div.inactive').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('inactive')
           .addClass('Active')
           .siblings('div')
           .removeClass('Active')
           .addClass('inactive');
    });
});
```

Note that event handlers are bound to selected elements not their class names, when you change the class name your handler will be executed regardless of the class name of the clicked element. You can use event delegation instead.

```
$('#aParentElement').on('click', '.Active', function(){
   // Click handler for the Active element
})

$('#aParentElement').on('click', '.inactive', function(){
   // Click handler for the inActive elements
   $(this).removeClass('inactive')
           .addClass('Active')
           .siblings('div')
           .removeClass('Active')
           .addClass('inactive');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'div.inactive', function() {
        //run some codes
        $('.Active').removeClass('Active').addClass('inactive');
        $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('Active');
    });
});
```

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgYyP/

Comment: This works partially. It removed the active and add the inactive but did not change the inactive to active for the clicked item

Comment: because this answer is only changing classes. Read what I wrote.

Comment: @imkost You have document ready and document click, is this correct or a mistakes?

Comment: @Bryan - It's a delegate from the `document`. You can do it, but I would strongly advice *against* it, as *every* click event will be processed at that point. This is bad practice in most use cases, and what got `$.live()` booted from the party.

Comment: @Bryan - Checkout http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/FEjKC/2/show/. Source: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/FEjKC/2/ You don't need to delegate from `document`.

Answer (score -1):

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FEjKC/4/)

Other answers have missed this point: *"If the user click on an inactive div, the class of that div should change to active and the previous div with the active class should be changed to inactive **making that a clickable options**"*

You are trying to control whether they can be clicked or not by the class name, but the problem is that the elements you bind the click to, div.inactive, **don't drop those binds when that class is removed** so you must check for this each time they are clicked, and bind the event to the Active ones too.

```
$('div.inactive, div.Active').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('inactive')){
        //run some codes
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().toggleClass('Active inactive');
    }
});
```

Comment: @popnoodles I checked the demo that was posted. In this demo there are only 2 div's and when I add a third it did not work. Like I said the div's are in a loop and will be more than 2 items. I need a solution for more than 2 items.

Comment: @Brian I added a third too and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/FEjKC/3/ Can you show us how yours looked?

Comment: @Bryan - [Little better layout of the `#container`](http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/FEjKC/2/show/).